# How to log regular expression extractor value in results when ran through blazemeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

How to log regular expression extractor value in results when ran through blaze-meter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're a BlazeMeter customer it could make more sense to contact [BlazeMeter Support](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket), most probably you will get more quick and professional response than trying to ask random people over the Internet for their opinions.

Whatever. What do you mean by "log"?

- If you need to write the value to [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) - just add __logn() function somewhere in your script like:

  ```
   ${__logn(My variable value is: ${foo},,)}
  ```

  replace `${foo}` with your actual variable name

  Once test finishes you will see the variable value in the `jmeter.log` file (you can download it as a part of **artifacts.zip** bundle from your test [Execution Logs](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000303897-Logs-Report-Logs-Report)
- If you want to track the variable value per each sampler - the easiest option is to configure [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property and provide your variable value there:

  [image]

  this way you will see an extra column in the **kpi.jtl** file containing your variable value

Artifacts view containing `kpi.jtl` and `jmeter.log` files

[image]